# Изменение сериализованного класса

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, имеется сериализации класс, в нем необходимо переопределить метод например toString, после переопределения ранее сериализованные объектов класса не десериализуются, как можно обойти эту проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Определите следующее статическое поле `serialVersionUID` с номером версии.

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

Пока ваши изменения в классе совместимы этот номер можно не менять. Без этого поля оно генерируется автоматически, то есть любые изменения класса меняют вычисленное значение этого поля, поэтому у вас и возникают проблемы во время десериализации.